# Remove the Close button in the program's title bar

Tags: c#

Goal:
Don't want the user to use the X mark (upper right of the program's screen) to exit the program.

Problem:
Don't know how to remove that icon that allows user to exit the program?

Comment: **Why**? Suppose that you found a way to remove this icon. What if the user presses `Shift+Alt+Esc` key combination on his keyboard and in the list of available processes he presses the `Del` key on your application? Would you want to disable this scenario as well? Personally I would hate an application which disables standard Windows things like the close button.

Comment: It's not a completely contrived use case.  Hell, they give you a property (ControlBox) out of the box that can disable it.

Comment: Go on, remove it. I'm more of an Alt+F4 guy anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I mean, it can make small dialogs look a bit more clean and enforces to the user that they need to do something other than "X" out of the window.  Of course, you still have to handle force close anyway.

Comment: Darin: good question. it's part of my assignment from school work.

Comment: I noticed some apps, like utorrent, use the X button to minimize to tray

Comment: Ok well that is just obnoxious behavior in that case.  The X should always close the window.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prevent a user from closing my C# application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655810/how-can-i-prevent-a-user-from-closing-my-c-application)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can set the [`ControlBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.controlbox.aspx) property to `false` if you don't want this to display. This will also remove the minimize and maximize buttons, mind you.

I would also ask you to consider why you want to remove this button. Sometimes it makes more sense to override the `OnFormClosing` method and optionally set `Cancel` to `true` under certain conditions (e.g., `e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing`).

Answer (score 11):

```
myForm.ControlBox = false;
```

Apparently I have to have at least 30 characters in my post, so I will say that I am assuming WinForms since you do not specify yourself.  Also note that setting this property to false will remove the minimize and maximize buttons as well.

Answer (score 4):

```
myform.ControlBox = false;
```

does it for me

Answer (score 2):

This guy seems to have figured it out:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/atosah/archive/2007/05/18/disable-close-x-button-in-winforms-using-c.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I used this and its working for me

```
this.ControlBox = false;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!